# Windows 10 Game Bar Stops Recording

Tags: windows, gaming, lenovo-laptop, screen-capture

I have a new Lenovo Y70 PC and I was trying to use it to record some gameplay of Deus Ex: Human Revolution Director's Cut. I set the limit to an hour and the entire time, I saw the timer in red in the upper right corner of my screen so I knew it was recording and I knew how much time I had left.

But when I stopped recording after about 55 minutes, and went to my Captures folder to retrieve the video, it was only 3 minutes long. It's as if the game bar stopped capturing on its own and truncated the video, even though the timer was clearly running for the whole 55 minutes.

I tried the same thing again, and the second time, I only got *15 seconds* of video.

What is going on here? I have tried searching around and could not find anything that describes the same problems. Does the game bar time out if it thinks it's not recording a game or something?

Answer (score -1):

Alternatives for recording gameplay:
Fraps, Dxtory, NVIDIA Shadowplay (this is really good for use, but only works with NVIDIA video cards), Plays.tv (alternative from Raptr/AMD), OBS. Try them and find what you looking for!

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an actual answer. Once you have sufficient reputation, you'll be able to comment everywhere.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for trying to help on this question.  Super User is a knowledge base, so answers are intended to be a little more substantive than just a list of products.  At a minimum, you should include links to the products and a brief description of the product and why it is a good solution.  Even better is to describe how to solve the question using the product.  Good guidance on how to recommend software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Just a heads up, your answer might attract downvotes as "low quality".